# UE 5 в главном меню спавнится игрок

Tags: unreal-engine-5

я сделал миню игры и когда я нажимаю на кнопку PLAY что бы протестировать кнопки "ИГРАТЬ" , "НАСТРОЙКИ" , "ВЫЙТИ" и когда нажимаю PLAY то появляется игрок(персонаж игрока(скин)) и он падает в бездну, надо сделать что бы он вообще не появлялся и была нормальная минюшка игры

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я сделал миню игры и когда я нажимаю на кнопку PLAY что бы протестировать кнопки "ИГРАТЬ" , "НАСТРОЙКИ" , "ВЫЙТИ" и когда нажимаю PLAY то появляется игрок(персонаж игрока(скин)) и он падает в бездну, надо сделать что бы он вообще не появлялся и была нормальная минюшка игры